# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'john' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using **ReactJS** in my SimpChat Application to upload data from my Register Form to the Firestore Database and I got an error that the Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'john' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found). Where did I got an error and how can I solve it? [image]

Here is my **Register Form** code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Add from "../img/addAvatar.png"
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, storage } from "../firebase";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { db } from "../firebase";


const Register = () => {
  const [err,setErr] = useState(false);
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    // console.log(e.target[0].value)
    const displayName = e.target[0].value;
    const email = e.target[1].value;
    const password = e.target[2].value;
    const file = e.target[3].files[0];

    try {
    const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)

    
    const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);
    
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
    
    // Register three observer
    uploadTask.on(
      (error) => {
        setErr(true);
      }, 
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
          await updateProfile (res.user, {
            displayName,
            photoURL: downloadURL,
          });

          await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid), {
            uid: res.user.uid,
            displayName,
            email,
            photoURL: downloadURL,
          });
        });
      }
    );

    } catch (err) {
      setErr(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='formContainer'>
        <div className='formWrapper'>
            
            <span className="logo">SimpChat</span>
            <span className="logo">Register</span>
            
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder='display name'/>
                <input type="email" placeholder='email' />
                <input type="password" placeholder='password' />
                <input style={{ display: "none" }} type="file" id='file' />
                <label htmlFor="file">
                    <img src={Add} alt="" />
                    <span>Add an avatar</span>
                </label>
                <button>Sign up</button>
                {err && <span>Something went wrong</span>}
            </form>

            <p>You do have an account? Login</p>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter in `uploadTask.on()` should be the event i.e. `state_changed`. Try:

```
// Ensure that all values are defined
console.log(file, displayName);

const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

uploadTask.on(
  'state_changed',
  (error) => {
    console.log('Error upload file', error)
    setErr(true);
  },
  () => {
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
      console.log({ downloadURL })
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the Firebase Storage object with the given reference does not exist. It could be because the file was not uploaded to the storage correctly, or there is an issue with the file reference.
To solve this issue, you can use a unique identifier for each user's uploaded file reference. One way to do this is by generating a UUID (Universal Unique Identifier) for each file upload

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

 try {
  const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  console.log(res.user);

  const fileId = uuidv4(); // Generate a UUID for the file reference
  const storageRef = ref(storage, `avatars/${res.user.uid}/${fileId}`);

  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

  uploadTask.on(
    'state_changed',
    (snapshot) => {
      // Handle upload progress here
      const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log(`Upload is ${progress}% done`);
    },
```